# find index based on first element in a nested list

Tags: list, indexing, nested

I have a list that contains sublists. The sequence of the sublist is fixed, as are the number of elements.

```
schedule = [['date1', 'action1', beginvalue1, endvalue1],
            ['date2', 'action2', beginvalue2, endvalue2],
            ...
           ]
```

Say, I have a date and I want find what I have to do on that date, meaning I require to find the contents of the entire sublist, given only the date.

I did the following (which works): I created a intermediate list, with all the first values of the sublists. Based on the index i was able to retrieve its entire contents, as follows:

```
dt = 'date150' # To just have a value to make underlying code more clear
ls_intermediate = [item[0] for item in schedule]
index = ls_intermediate.index(dt)

print(schedule[index])
```

It works but it just does not seem the Python way to do this. How can I improve this piece of code?

To be complete: there are no double 'date' entries in the list. Every date is unique and appears only once.

Learning Python, and having quite a journey in front of me...
thank you!